# I am a Vampire to the Day

Tags: riddle, word

> Want to meet me?
>
> Fat chance 'cause there are only two main places,
>
> Where you can see my beauty.
>
> Many names I have, but one that is universal
>
> I am a vampire to the day yet rely on the sun.
>
> Similar to a peacock I am, yet I do not live.
>
> There are varying elements that make me who I am,
>
> So, can you figure out who I am?

Comment: I was thinking that electrons can be at at **two places** simultaneously ("two main places"), which is definitely something **beautiful** ("see my beauty", physicists were awarded the Nobel Prize for this discovery!) and is part of **quantum** physics ("QuantumTwinkie")... is this related?

Comment: Wow, That sounds related, but I was not even intending that to be the answer! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> [Aurora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora#Visual_forms_and_colors)

Want to meet me? 
Fat chance 'cause there are only two main places,

> Aurorae can generally only be seen in high latitude regions (around the Arctic and Antarctic - Aurora borealis and Aurora australis).

Where you can see my beauty.

> Indeed it is a beautiful sight.

Many names I have, but one that is universal

> Aurora comes from the Latin word for "dawn, morning light"

I am a vampire to the day yet rely on the sun.

> An aurora can generally not be seen by eye during the day but are vibrant in darkness. Aurorae are produced when the magnetosphere is sufficiently disturbed by the solar wind.

Similar to a peacock I am, yet I do not live.

> The aurorae come in several different colours but mainly green and blue, similar to a peacock's feathers.

There are varying elements that make me who I am,

> The Wikipedia link describes various circumstances and elements that bring about aurorae

Comment: This is correct, good job :D

Comment: This is such a beautiful riddle

Answer (score 3):

Could you be:

> A night blooming flower?

Fat chance 'cause there are only two main places,

Where you can see my beauty.

> Not sure about this one, but I am sure some of these flowers are only in a few places

Many names I have, but one that is universal

> Again, might be a specific flower that has a common name and a scientific name.

I am a vampire to the day yet rely on the sun.

> Night blooming flowers still need photosynthesis, but the hide until the sun is gone.

Similar to a peacock I am, yet I do not live.

> Whoops

There are varying elements that make me who I am,

> Nevermind

So, can you figure out who I am?

Comment: Forgot to read the second to last clue....

Comment: $(+1)$ For the honesty :)

Answer (score 3):

Another possible answer, though still not likely:

Could you be:

> The moon?

Fat chance 'cause there are only two main places,

Where you can see my beauty.

> You can only see the moon from earth and the moon(?)

Many names I have, but one that is universal

> The moon has had many names in history, and different mythologies. Now, it is universally called the moon.

I am a vampire to the day yet rely on the sun.

> You can't usually see the moon in daytime, but without the sun it would have no light.

Similar to a peacock I am, yet I do not live.

> Moon is not alive, but it is pretty like a peacock (??)

There are varying elements that make me who I am,

> Moon is made of many elements

So, can you figure out who I am?

> I'm doing my best!

Comment: Very creative yet incorrect, This answer is closer, than the last :D

Comment: Dammit, now I have to work on this later tonight. You haven't won yet, Twinkie.

Comment: I posted one last riddle, in case you hadn't seen it. We both have something to work on XD

Comment: LOL, I am switching between this tab and your puzzle :)

Comment: Same man. May the best puzzler win

Comment: This is the best comment conversation I've seen on Puzzling :D

Comment: You can see the moon at daytime